# How to put an image and write text in same UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I want to put an image in my UILabel which should be right aligned and write some text in the same UILabel which should be left aligned. How can i do that programatically? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set that image as background image

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"]];
```

and write text as

```
thelabel.text =  @"abc"
```

set the align of the label

```
[thelabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

Comment: Won't this repeat the image? This happens to me in the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can actually put an image inside a UILabel, but if you can, you'll be using the addSubView: method.

```
UILabel *label = ....
label.text = @"Hi there";

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[label addSubView:image];
```

Try it out and see if it works, if not, then you'll probably have to set the image's frame to a frame that floats along with the label's.

Comment: I think you get "No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'addSubView:'"